# Matrix operation to exponentiate each element in a vector

Tags: matrices, exponentiation, kronecker-product, hadamard-product

I am using the following matrix algebra to obtain a vector, however, I eventually need all the resulting elements to be exponentiated.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\boldsymbol{\beta}^{\textsf{T}}\mathbf{X}^{\textsf{T}}&=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \beta_1 & \beta_2 & \beta_3 & \beta_4  \\
\end{bmatrix}  
\begin{bmatrix}
 {x_{11} }  & {x_{21} }  & \cdots  & {x_{41} }  \\
 {x_{12} }  & {x_{22} }  & \cdots  & {x_{42} }  \\
 \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots  \\
 {x_{14} }  & {x_{24} }  & \cdots  & {x_{44} }  \\
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
 \mathbf{x}_1\boldsymbol{\beta} &  \mathbf{x}_2\boldsymbol{\beta} &  \mathbf{x}_3\boldsymbol{\beta} &  \mathbf{x}_4\boldsymbol{\beta}  \\
\end{bmatrix}  
\end{split}
\end{equation}

What operation would I use to exponentiate each vector element in $\boldsymbol{\beta}^{\textsf{T}}\mathbf{X}^{\textsf{T}}$ to obtain:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \exp(\mathbf{x}_1\boldsymbol{\beta}) &  \exp(\mathbf{x}_2\boldsymbol{\beta}) &  \exp(\mathbf{x}_3\boldsymbol{\beta}) &  \exp(\mathbf{x}_4\boldsymbol{\beta})  \\
\end{bmatrix}  
\end{equation}

The rationale for asking is because I simply just can't introduce a vector whose elements are exponentiated, so I am thinking along the lines of a Kronecker or Hadamard type operation that can exponentiate all elements of a vector.  Hence, what would the notation be?

Comment: Not sure what you really want but consider both Kronecker and Hadamard product consists of finite operations of multiplication. On the contrary, exponential is an operation that requires infinite operations of multiplication and addition as you know for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $\exp x =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$. So, I doubt there is any. If you allow infinite operations, then you may use matrix exponential. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Comment: I did search and noticed that someone simply used $e^{\mathbf{X}}$, which would be similar to me using $e^{\boldsymbol{\beta}^{\textsf{T}}\mathbf{X}^{\textsf{T}}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "vector exponential" of ${\bf x} := \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_n \end{bmatrix}^\top$ can be obtained as follows

$$ \exp\left( \mbox{diag} ({\bf x}) \right) \,{\bf 1}_n$$

Comment: What is $\text{diag}(\mathbf{x})$ for a non-square matrix? (Like the $4 \times 1$ matrix described here?)

Comment: @SelrachDunbar https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html

Comment: Nice.  Thanks for the reference.

Comment: So, just to close the loop, using: (i) the $\bf\mbox{diag}$ operator (which takes in a vector and gives back a square matrix) and (ii) the $\mathbf{\exp}$ operator (which takes in a square matrix and gives back a different square matrix), the answer to the question in the original post can be written as

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \exp(\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_1 & \exp(\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_2 & \exp(\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_3 & \exp(\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_4  \end{bmatrix}=\left( \exp\left( \mbox{diag} (\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}) \right) \,{\bf 1}_n\right)^\intercal.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}$ is a vector with 4 rows an 1 column.  We denote this vector $\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} = \begin{bmatrix}
 (\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_1 \\
 (\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_2 \\
 (\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_3 \\
 (\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_4 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ So,

$\boldsymbol{\beta}^{\textsf{T}}\mathbf{X}^{\textsf{T}} = \left(\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)^\textsf{T} = \begin{bmatrix}
 (\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_1 \\
 (\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_2 \\
 (\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_3 \\
 (\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_4 \\
\end{bmatrix}^\textsf{T} $ $ = \begin{bmatrix} (\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_1 & (\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_2 & (\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_3 & (\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_4  \end{bmatrix}$.

If you want the row vector obtained by making each of the four values in this last matrix the exponent of the number $e$, you can write this as

$$\begin{bmatrix} \exp(\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_1 & \exp(\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_2 & \exp(\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_3 & \exp(\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})_4  \end{bmatrix} =\sum_{k=1}^4 \left[\exp(\bf{e_k}^\intercal\cdot\bf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})\right] \bf{e_k^{\;\intercal}} $$
where $\bf{e_k}$ is the $k^{th}$ column of the identity matrix (or equivalently, $\bf{e_k^{\;\intercal}}$ is the $k^{th}$ row of the identity matrix).